# Goto next iteration $.each if ajax is completed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, each

See the code below, it seem it execute many `$.post` without waiting for `data == "1"`

It should go next iteration (`$.each`) if `data` is equal to `1`.

How can it be done?

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
  $.post("tracking.php",  { action: "send", id: getId }, function(data) {
    if (data == "1") {
      //
    }
  },'json');
});
```

Comment: That's called "asynchronous". You won't be able to use `$.each()` to loop this way

Comment: Don't understand why I got vote downs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$.post` is asynchronous, you can't use it to control the looping. You can use a structure like:

```
var data = [1, 2, 3];

function iterator(arr) {
    function iterate(i) {
        // Use `arr[i]`
        $.post("tracking.php",  { action: "send", id: getId }, function(data) {
            if (data == "1") {
                iterate(++i);
            }
        }, "json");
    }
    iterate(0);
}

iterator(data);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ezwj4/

Of course, in the demo, I had to modify the code/parameters to make it work with jsFiddle. Notice how it stops after the response isn't `"1"` (which is just the value in the array, because I needed to just echo the value to show how it would work). You can watch your browser's console to see what's happening.

**UPDATE:**

To be sure the array's bounds aren't exceeded, you need to check its length. Here's an update:

```
function iterator(arr) {
    // You can use `arr` anywhere inside of `iterator`
    function iterate(i) {
        // You can use `i` anywhere inside of `iterate`
        if (i < arr.length) {
            $.post("tracking.php",  { action: "send", id: getId }, function(data) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    iterate(++i);
                }
            }, "json");
        }
    }
    iterate(0);
}
```

Comment: Would `$.ajax()` make any different and easier?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Not really, at least in your case - it's just a shortcut for `$.ajax()` with specific things set. I like using `$.ajax()` in every case, because I like being explicit (and you can set any option for the `$.ajax()` call, instead of the specific ones `$.post()` allows), but I don't see it helping/hurting you, if you like using `$.post`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use check `arr.length` before executing `iterate(++i);` ?

Comment: Maybe  `if (arr.length != i) { iterate(++i); }` ?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Oh jeez, you're absolutely right - that needs to be checked. Give me a minute

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I just updated my answer with what I'd use. I'd rather keep it outside of the `$.post` callback. Especially, if for some reason, `arr` initially has no items and therefore a length of `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can call the first `post` request using the first index of the array `data` then wait for `response(data)` to return then fire another `post` request on the next index an so on:

```
function posts(index) {
  $.post("tracking.php",  { action: "send", id: getId }, function(response) {
    if (response == "1") {
       index++;
       if (index < data.length) post(index); //call the function "post" again only if index is lower than the array "data" length.
       }
    }
  },'json');
});
posts(0);
```

Comment: You should definitely add some explanations. It would improve the quality of the answer for future visitors of the question!

Comment: `index < data.length` doesnt make sense.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back `index < data.length` will check if the index reached the last childNode inside the array `data` see the explanation above for more details

Comment: `data` is a variable from ajax data - its not an array.

Comment: this --> `$.each(data, function(index) {` means data is an array, and in the answer you accepted data was declared as an array --> `var data = [1, 2, 3];`, so what do u mean it's a variable?

Answer (score -1):

With $.each and an async request you can't control the execution of the loop, however, with a for loop you can done it:

```
for(var index in data){
    data = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url:"tracking.php",  
        data: { action: "send", id: getId }, 
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function(tmpData){
          data = tmpData
        }
    });
    if(data != '1'){
        break;
    }
}
```

In this example, we use a for loop and a jQuery sync ajax request to get the result from the server and verify if the value is expected. If something different of "1" is returned, we simply break (stopping) the loop.